# VirtualBox fails to start with VERR_NEM_VM_CREATE_FAILED

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox

Immediately after starting a VM in VirtualBox, I receive a error box that contains the following error message:

> Call to WHvSetupPartition failed: ERROR_SUCCESS (Last=0xc000000d/87) (VERR_NEM_VM_CREATE_FAILED).

I am running Windows 10 Professional, Version 1903 and have confirmed that Hyper-V is not enabled.

Comment: Are you running Windows 10 Professional?

Comment: I got the same problem and none of the solutions from here doesn't work for me. Could you please take a look on my question - https://superuser.com/questions/1508514/verr-nem-vm-create-failed-on-launching-macos-in-virtualbox-in-win-10-1903

Comment: I don't have enough rep on this SE site to post this as an answer (perhaps someone else would though?), but I just managed to get my VMs to launch in VBox 6.2 on a Win10 Pro 1903 host with both "Hyper-V" and "Windows Hypervisor Platform" features installed: I just needed to update my VBox global config with `VBoxManage setextradata global "VBoxInternal/NEM/UseRing0Runloop" 0`. See [this VBox forum post](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=90853&sid=f20b0f7f51e462005f9b3be80a567617&start=120#p453078) for details.

Comment: Minor correction to my previous comment (too late to edit it now): I meant in VirtualBox 6**.1**.2..

Comment: @ZaLiTHkA you could ask a new question and tick the "Answer your own question" box

Comment: I received this very same error message. This happened even after unticking "Hyper-V" and "Windows sandbox" from "Windows features". However, I could finally start my VM after unticking "Containers", "Virtual Machine Platform" and "Windows Process Activation Service", and restarting Windows twice.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

1. Open the "**Turn Windows features on or off**" settings (type `optionalfeatures` in the start menu or <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>).
2. Untick "**Windows Sandbox**" and "**Hyper-V**" .
3. Restart windows twice.

This is a new feature in Windows 10 v1903 that uses Hyper-V on the backend (even if it's not enabled in Windows Features), which makes this feature not compatible with VirtualBox.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I am also facing this same issue. In my machine both hyper-v and sandbox not enabled (both are untick). Any other suggestions?

Comment: Two reboots are needed after disabling Windows Sandbox

Comment: In my case was unchecking "Windows Hypervisor Platform"

Comment: The "Windows Sandbox" can't appear for some people that are not using Windows 10 on english language (my case, I'm using Brazilian Portuguese). On that case, you can use the command line to disable it: `Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName "Containers-DisposableClientVM" -Online`

Comment: i also had to disable "Docker for windows"m seems to re-enable Hyper-V

Comment: It seems that Microsoft is re-enabling Hyper-V even if we disable it with those feature updates. (Hyper-V was re-enabled on my Windows 10 PC after upgrading to 1903 without telling me...)

Comment: I got the same problem and solutions from here doesn't work for me. Could you please take a look on my question - https://superuser.com/questions/1508514/verr-nem-vm-create-failed-on-launching-macos-in-virtualbox-in-win-10-1903

Comment: I had to untick "Virtual Machine Platform" & reboot twice.

Comment: Just rebooting twice might be a good idea to try, the only common denominator in all solutions here is the reboot twice

Comment: Had to reboot twice to get this working (unchecked both Hyper-V and sandbox).

Comment: This didn't help. I just grabbed a newer version of VirtualBox 6.1.18 and it worked fine.

Comment: Really annoying that this affects VirtualBox! Sandbox is useful as well, but now I have to turn it off in order to get my VBs running. :-(

Answer (score 33):

According to [this VirtualBox forum post](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=93443#p450399), there are several features which might use Microsoft Hyper-V, which is not compatible with VirtualBox:

> Look in the "Control Panel" » "Programs and Features" » "Turn Windows features on or off", and make sure that the none of the following are active:

- Application Guard
- Credential Guard
- Device Guard
- *<any>* * Guard
- Containers
- Hyper-V
- Virtual Machine Platform
- Windows Hypervisor Platform
- Windows Sandbox
- Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)

If that doesn't work, enter the following command:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

followed by a cold boot, i.e. shut down the computer, pull the power plug for 10 seconds, reboot.

For me, just disabling "Virtual Machine Platform" and restarting **TWICE** made it work.

WSL 1 will still work. I'm not so sure about WSL 2, which is currently available in the Windows Insider Program.

Comment: I can confirm that "Virtual Machine Platform" feature is required for WSL 2
Also mentioned here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-install

Comment: In my case, I had to uninstall Windows Defender Application Guard and reboot. Other solutions did not work.

Comment: Yep, I've just enabled "Virtual Machine Platform" to try WSL2 and VirtualBox broke. Disabling the component and restarting the notebook twice brought VirtualBox back to life again.

Comment: Virtual Machine Platform is he one that got me :)

Answer (score 30):

Finally solved the issue.

1. Turn off Hyper-v
2. Turn off Windows sandbox

by navigating to "Turn windows features on or off".

Restart the machine **twice** and then try to Start vm in virtualbox.

Comment: Restart twice EVEN if Windows sandbox was already off and only Hyper-v was turned off did the trick!

Comment: Also turn off "Containers"

Comment: Double reboots helped me!

Comment: worked for me too! thank you, life saver!

Answer (score 11):

In my case, turning *Windows Sandbox* and *Hyper-V* off and restarting my PC dozens of times didn't work. I even tried turning the features back on, then back off, then restarting another dozen times.

What *did* work, was disabling *Memory integrity* from *Core isolation* in *Windows Security*, possibly because it uses virtualization features, as do Hyper-V and the Windows Sandbox.

[image: Windows Security screenshot]

Now I can finally start my VMs again.

Comment: this worked for me

Comment: This also worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: I had this exact same problem, on a fresh windows 10 install, 21H1, with VirtualBox 6.0.4.  The common fix of turning off windows features did not work. But this solution worked for me immediately. Thank you.

Comment: After trying the solution given by @aman207, THIS is what worked for me. I'm using VBox 6.0.14 running on Win10 pro compilation 19042 version 20H2

Answer (score 8):

I've gone through that same problem too and it was caused due to having an older version on my machine at that given time (version 6.0.22).

[image]

In order to solve it, I've gone to [Virtual Box's download page](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads), downloaded the version 6.1.16 for Windows hosts and installed this newer version

[image]

Then, as you can see in the next images, that error is gone

[image]

Comment: Surprisingly, this was exactly the solution for me - nothing else helped until I updated from 6.1.2 to 6.1.32 . I can't find the words to explain how I feel about the quality of error messages.

Comment: It is 2024, and ever since I did a big Windows update five months ago, my virtual machine wouldn't start. Today I installed the latest version of Virtual Box (7 something), and now it works again. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Hyper-V needs to be disabled but not uninstalled. I wanted to maintain Hyper-V functions some of the time and have the option to reboot into windows with Hyper-V disabled.

I ran the following in an *administrator* powershell prompt:

```
bcdedit /copy {current} /d "Windows 10 no Hyper-V"
```

> The entry was successfully copied to {95524711-fa90-11e9-b0c8-927c2d2c6eb6}.

Copy the GUID into the next command:

```
bcdedit /set "{95524711-fa90-11e9-b0c8-927c2d2c6eb6}" hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

> The operation completed successfully.

Click restart **while holding the <kbd>shift</kbd> button And keep holding <kbd>shift</kbd>**

[image: screenshot of restart]

Select "Other Operating Systems" and your "No Hyper-V" option is in there.

[image: boot menu]
[image: Boot Options]

If you want to change the default mode (either with hyper-v enabled or disabled), run `msconfig` and change the default on the boot tab.

[image: msconfig screenshot]

Thanks to [Scott Hanselman](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/SwitchEasilyBetweenVirtualBoxAndHyperVWithABCDEditBootEntryInWindows81.aspx) for inspiring this post.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to disable Containers! Here's how to do it based on this [article](https://www.tcg.com/blog/yes-you-can-run-docker-and-virtualbox-on-windows-10-home/)

```
VBoxManage setextradata "<VM Name>" "VBoxInternal/NEM/UseRing0Runloop" 0
```

Comment: While this helped with creation of the VM, I ran into the next problem later ("Attempting fall back to NEM")...

Answer (score 1):

**When Docker Desktop is running**

When you currently do not need any docker container, that is running on your system, it is sufficient to close docker desktop by right clicking the icon in the right on your task bar:

[image: docker desktop icon]

Then select "Quit Docker Desktop" and the VM is supposed to run again. You can even restart Docker Desktop after that and relaunch your containers without breaking either the VM or containers.

(For sure not every functionality is guaranteed, but it's worth a test.)

Newer versions of Virtual Box are probably better in doing so (my post was created with VirtualBox 6.1)