# Kali Linux : Failed to open session for virtual machine is failed on Windows 10

Tags: linux, windows-10, virtualbox, virtualization, kali-linux

I installed Virtual Box 6.0 in Windows 10 OS and then downloaded 64 bit ***ova*** file for Kali Linux. I created NAT network for communication between host and guest operating system.

When starting Kali Linux getting following error:

[image: Some Kali Linux error]

**Note** : Virtualization is enabled and Hyperv is disabled for Windows 10.
Also, Hyper-v and Windows Sandbox is disabled.

How to solve this error?

I have tried solution mentioned below link but not worked for me :
[VirtualBox fails to start with VERR_NEM_VM_CREATE_FAILED](https://superuser.com/questions/1442766/virtualbox-fails-to-start-with-verr-nem-vm-create-failed)

Comment: Did you really restarted twice as many recommended?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia the settings were already unchecked so restarting wont affect anything.

Comment: According to this answer, You need to disable "Windows Hypervisor Platform" needs to be disabled *along with* Hyper-v. You may also need to disable "Windows Defender Application Guard ". https://superuser.com/questions/1391838/virtual-box-is-not-working-on-windows-10?rq=1

Comment: Also, https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=92260 mentions this exact error.