# VERR_NEM_VM_CREATE_FAILED on launching macOS in VirtualBox in Win 10 1903

Tags: virtualbox, hyper-v, windows-10-v1903

I'm trying to launch virtual machine from VirtualBox(6.0.14-133895 with extension pack) on Windows 64bit 10 Pro version 1903 18362.476 and frustratingly get the following error:

```
Call to WHvSetupPartition failed: ERROR_SUCCESS (Last=0xc000000d/87) 
(VERR_NEM_VM_CREATE_FAILED).

Result Code: 
E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: 
ConsoleWrap
Interface: 
IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

I tried everything from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1507986/virtualbox-error-verr-nem-vm-create-failed), [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1442766/virtualbox-fails-to-start-with-verr-nem-vm-create-failed), [here](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=93443), [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1502529/call-to-whvsetuppartition-failed-error-success-last-0xc000000d-87-verr-nem-v?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://www.sysnative.com/forums/threads/windows-10-version-1903-hyper-v-is-currently-incompatible-with-virtualbox-6-0-x.28466/): turn off features Containers, Hyper-V, Windows Sandbox, Virtual Machine Platform, Windows Defender Application Guard, Windows Hypervisor Platform, Linux subsystem, turn off Core Isolation Memory Integrity, disable VT-d in BIOS, reboot machine dozens of times, reinstall VirtualBox and reboot again. Tried this command also:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

Nothing happens, I still get this error. I got Docker on my machine and everytime after reboot, system tells me that:

```
Hyper-V and Containers features are not enabled.
Do you want to enable them for Docker to be able to work properly?
Your computer will restart automatically.
Note: VirtualBox will no longer work.
```

Please help!

P.S. Here is my BIOS preferences:
[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about running macOS on non-Apple hosts, which is against the EULA and not supported.

Comment: Docker is the issue.  Docker requires Hyper-V.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VirtualBox fails to start with VERR\_NEM\_VM\_CREATE\_FAILED](https://superuser.com/questions/1442766/virtualbox-fails-to-start-with-verr-nem-vm-create-failed)

Comment: Docker doesn't work at the moment, because Hyper-V is disabled. Do you think, that Docker can keep Hyper-V implicitly turned-on? As for mentioned question - of course I have tried every solution from there=(

Comment: What happens when you turn VT-D on in your BIOS?

Comment: Nothing happens actually.

Answer (score 1):

This helped me with exactly the same error:

> My hunch was that turning on Sandox activated some part of Hyper-V which was not deactivated when Sandbox was turned off so I installed Hyper-V (no Sandbox), rebooted and then immediately uninstalled Hyper-V and rebooted twice. No more error message. Both VM's working as I expect them to.

by fieldar from https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=92453&start=75