# VirtualBox Error: VERR_NEM_VM_CREATE_FAILED

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I had an update yesterday and since then is not working. (not sure is that's the reason, I didn't start VM in the last 2 weeks)

Starting a VM in VirtualBox, I receive a error box that contains the following error message:

> Call to WHvSetupPartition failed: ERROR_SUCCESS (Last=0xc000000d/87) (VERR_NEM_VM_CREATE_FAILED).

This is my configuration:

1. Turn off Hyper-v
2. Turn off Windows sandbox
3. Application Guard (doesn't appear on list)
4. Credential Guard (doesn't appear on list)
5. Turn off Device Guard (doesn't appear on list)
6. Turn off Guard (doesn't appear on list)
7. Turn off Containers
8. Turn off Virtual Machine Platform
9. Turn off Windows Hypervisor Platform
10. Core isolation>Memory integrity is OFF
11. SVM Enabled on Bios
12. tried running this `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off` CMD as
    administrator

Windows 10 64bits Version 1909 (OS build 18363.476)

Restarted windows few times

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ijfz1.png

Update: uninstalling and installing VirtualBox worked.

Comment: Windows Sandbox and associated software is a Hyper-V implementation. It conflicts with VMware Workstation and may well conflict with Virtual Box.  I had to disable Sandbox and reinstall VMware Workstation. Try uninstalling and reinstalling Virtual Box and then restart again

Comment: So I will post my comment as an answer and I assume you will accept it then

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VirtualBox fails to start with VERR\_NEM\_VM\_CREATE\_FAILED](https://superuser.com/questions/1442766/virtualbox-fails-to-start-with-verr-nem-vm-create-failed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Sandbox and associated software is a Hyper-V implementation. It conflicts with VMware Workstation and may well conflict with Virtual Box. I had to disable Sandbox and reinstall VMware Workstation. Try uninstalling and reinstalling Virtual Box and then restart again

Comment: I did take a look.  The error in that case may be the result of trying to make MAC OS a guest machine which is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

I updated my **VirtualBox6** to **VirtualBox7** and it worked for me.
Hope this will help you guys as well.