# i7-7700k Intel Virtualization Technology not working when attempting to use VirtualBox

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, cpu, virtualization

I am trying to run a VirtualBox and I am getting VT-x disabled error. I have a i7-7700k which should be able to run Virtualbox AND I have used it in the past and it worked.

Intel processor identification utility says Intel virtualization technology is disabled for some weird reason

**Specs**

- Windows 10
- GTX 1080 TI
- ASUS Maximus IX Apex
- 16 GB DDR4

**Here are the things I've tried**

- Virtualization technology is ENABLED in BIOS
- Containers, Hyper-V, Virtual Machine Platform are all DISABLED in Windows Features
- Tried this command:

  ```
  dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V
  ```

and `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`

- Tried everything in this post: [VT-x not available in Windows 10 Pro even though i5-6400 CPU supports VT-X](https://superuser.com/questions/1366264/vt-x-not-available-in-windows-10-pro-even-though-i5-6400-cpu-supports-vt-x)

Comment: Something that has worked for me in past. Start in BIOS and then select the option to Reset BIOS to Defaults. Restart. This does undo Virtualization. Go back to BIOS and just change the one variable (check that there is just one and not two variables - that depends on your BIOS).  Restart again and check your virtual machine again.

Comment: @JakeGould Edited it. As i said though I used to use it in the past and it worked. I dont think its because of my hardware

Comment: @John Will try that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VirtualBox Error: VERR\_NEM\_VM\_CREATE\_FAILED](https://superuser.com/questions/1507986/virtualbox-error-verr-nem-vm-create-failed)

Comment: Use the [Intel](https://superuser.com/questions/1474059/does-my-cpu-motherboard-support-vt-x/1474286#1474286) to verify VT-x support is enabled.  Edit your question to indicate if the tool indicates if VT-x is enabled or disabled.  Additional list any optional Windows features you have installed.

Comment: try to turn off Core isolation, Application Guard, Credential Guard, Device Guard and Windows Sandbox. [They also make use of Hyper-V](https://superuser.com/a/1418663/241386)

Answer (score 0):

Open elevated `cmd.exe` and run `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`, and then restart system.

Comment: Tried that, didn't work unfortunately