# Why does this VirtualBox error appear? Call to VidMessageSlotMap failed: Last=0xc000000d/87 (VERR_NEM_VM_CREATE_FAILED)

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, bios

When I attempt to start an Ubuntu guest OS in VirtualBox it gives me this error:

```
Call to VidMessageSlotMap failed: Last=0xc000000d/87 (VERR_NEM_VM_CREATE_FAILED)
```

[image]

I was getting more common errors (AMD-V) relating to virtualization beforehand. I am aware of issues with Windows 10, AMD, and virtualization. I had enabled SVM Support in the BIOS and it solved those issues, but this one is now appearing which it didn't before.

When I search this error I get information relating to "WHvSetupPartition" and not "VidMessageSlotMap". I tried the fixes for that (including the powershell command: `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`) with this one too, but they didn't work.

"Your question has been identified as a possible duplicate of another question."
As mentioned, it's a different error and I've tried fixes for that error on this too.

I am using Windows 10 Pro N, a Ryzen 5 1600, and a Gigabyte B450M DS3H. As I said I enabled SVM in the BIOS and I am sure to have disabled the Windows 10 based virtualization features as they were apparently causing issues too. I attempted with them both enabled and disabled.

[image]

I've highlighted the ones I've heard are the ones that may conflict with it and as you can see they're all disabled.

What is causing this and how do I disable it or prevent it from doing so? Or what may I need to enable to get this working?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VirtualBox fails to start with VERR\_NEM\_VM\_CREATE\_FAILED](https://superuser.com/questions/1442766/virtualbox-fails-to-start-with-verr-nem-vm-create-failed)

Comment: @Ramhound - It doesn't help because it talks about a different error: "Call to WHvSetupPartition failed", whereas this one is "Call to VidMessageSlotMap failed", and I've mentioned this and how I still tried the same fixes to no avail in the OP.

As the screenshot shows I have disabled all the Windows 10 virtualization, along with restarting multiple times. I don't get any other errors than what VB shows, however what other software may be (somehow) still using it as I haven't used virtualization on this machine before? Thanks.

Comment: You should also verify you are NOT using an Insider Preview build of 20H1 or 20H2.

Comment: I was able to install it with *Windows Subsystem for Linux* checked. The others I also had to uncheck because neither *VirtualBox* nor *Intel HAXM* could be installed. But apparently, your issue is beyond that.

Comment: @Ramhound - Just Malwarebytes, tried it with it closed too. Core Isolation is off, should I try it with it enabled? Not sure where to look to find those Guards. Yes I've ran the command; will edit post to show this. Also I'm not using either build but I am using an "N" version of Windows, I think this only effects Windows Media related software though.

Comment: @CristiFati - It was the Virtual Machine Platform that fixed it but this too works with it.

Comment: I got this same error today after I installed Docker Desktop on Windows.

Comment: I also experience the same issue after installation of Docker Desktop. Should I uninstall Docker Desktop to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was getting the same error. Leaving **Virtual Machine Platform** on made VM run.

Comment: Yeah I tried this and it worked, thank you. Also was able to enable _Windows Subsystem for Linux_ and it still worked.

Comment: No, didn't work for me, it just disabled my interet connection!

Comment: What is "**Virtual Machine Platform**", and how do I leave it on?

Comment: @jake, its a windows feature, in the windows search bar search "turn windows features"

Answer (score 3):

My problem was started when i have enable WSl2 in windows 10 machine. But
i am able to run WSL2 and Virtual Box by following steps:-

1. Open Virtualbox
2. Click on File Menu
3. Select Check for update
4. This will download a file in your downloads
5. Click on downloaded file and follow the steps

My error is gone after installing below version.
Version 6.1.16 r140961 (Qt5.6.2)

Happy troubleshooting.

Comment: Thank you this should be top comment

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same error :

```
Call to VidMessageSlotMap failed: Last=0xc000000d/87 (VERR_NEM_VM_CREATE_FAILED).
```

I resolved this with a second reboot of the system.
Hyper-V functionality and Windows containers were already disabled:

```
Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName containers
```

I use French Windows 10 Pro.
I have none of the following items: "Vitual Machine Platform", "Windows Hypervisor", "Windows Sandbox", "Windows Subsystem for Linux".

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to update Windows to latest version and install latest version of VirtualBox (& if you used, you can update ExtensionsPack too)
2. if above doesn't solve, try https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=95978

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue after installing **Docker Desktop** and here is how I resolved this issue.

- Open the "**Turn Windows features on or off**" settings (type `optionalfeatures` in the start menu or Win + R).
- Uncheck "**Windows Machine Platform**" and "**Windows Subsystem for Linux**" .
- Restart windows once or twice.

[image]

[image]

- If you have Docker Desktop installed, then after restart you will see the following message.

[image]

I think the above message is telling that you have to check `Windows subsystem for Linux` and `Virtual machine Platform` for running Docker Desktop.

If you want to work on Docker Desktop again, you can check these options a see that are you able to use Docker Desktop or not. I haven't checked it myself so I can't tell you the result.

**UPDATE - 2023**

If above solution couldn't work, please try to update the VirtualBox.
I installed the latest version of VirtualBox which is version-7 at the time of writing this update and it fixed my issue.

Hope this will help.