# VirtualBox 6.1 cannot start VM with Docker+WSL in Windows

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, docker, hyper-v

I need to run VirtualBox 6.1, Docker, and WSL for my projects. Yes, I can turn off HyperV and WSL, restart, use VirtualBox, turn them on, restart, use Docker & WSL1, but this is so tedious. According to VirtualBox support of HyperV starts from 6.x versions, and I followed every step of [this blog](https://www.tcg.com/blog/yes-you-can-run-docker-and-virtualbox-on-windows-10-home/) on transforming my Kali Linux VM to Hyper-V. However I still got this error:

```
Failed to get device handle and/or partition ID for 0000000001be10e0 (hPartitionDevice=0000000000000ba5, Last=0xc0000002/1) (VERR_NEM_VM_CREATE_FAILED).

Result Code: 
E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: 
ConsoleWrap
Interface: 
IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

How to solve this?

Comment: The error you received is a VirtualBox error not a Hyper-V error. What exactly is your question? VirtualBox is indeed compatible with WSL2 and the required virtualization optional windows feature it requires. The article you link to is about Hyper-V within a VirtualBox VM.

Comment: @Ramhound My problem is that I encountered this error before when not turning off Hyper-V. I want them (VB & Docker) to run together, but I got this error starting Kali Linux VM in VirtualBox. I would like to know how to solve this.

Comment: You can use Docker within WSL2 or Docker Desktop.  If you choose Docker Desktop, you will have to enable Hyper-V. WSL2 requires `Virtual Machine Platform` which is compatible with VirtualBox. The compatibility issue you are running into is Docker Desktop and VirtualBox.  Hyper-V support is experimental, and while you can have Hyper-V and install VirtualBox, you will see a huge performance hit by doing so.  My suggestion is to use WSL2 and VirtualBox and uninstall Hyper-V and only install Virtual Machine Platform`. However, most users, cannot get it working likely due to their hardware

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is likely a duplicate of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1442766/virtualbox-fails-to-start-with-verr-nem-vm-create-failed) question

Comment: @Ramhound Turning off Hyper-V, Windows Sandbox (already off), Windows Hypervisor Platform, *and* WSL didn't work for me...

Comment: @Power_tile - You are running Windows 10 21H1?

Comment: @Ramhound It worked! I reinstalled VBox and I can open the VM. Then I only enabled WSL in features and now I can also use Docker and WSL!!! Btw I am using Windows 11.