# VERR_NEM_VM_CREATE_FAILED makes conflict for Docker and VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, docker

When I launch the VM in VirtualBox, I got the error VERR_NEM_VM_CREATE_FAILED. According to this [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1442766/virtualbox-fails-to-start-with-verr-nem-vm-create-failed), the Virtual Machine Platform feature must be turned off to run the VM. That works, however it makes the Docker failed to start. I do not want to turn on/off the feature and restart the machine whenever I want to use one of them.

Comment: Try using Hyper-V or VMware Workstation instead of Virtual Box to run all you want.

Comment: What version of VirtualBox? What version of Windows 10/11? [Edit] your question to include any vital information required to answer your question.

Comment: @Ramhound Windows 10 Pro, VBox 6.0, Docker 4.12.0